# Magento custom attribute label

Tags: magento

I have created a custom attribute for the billing address on my magneto backed (Sales-> order -> billing address). However, the attribute input field is showing on the backend without the label. like this
[image: custom attribute field]

My backend array for this label is like this.

```
 $attributes = array(
    'buildingnumber' => array(
       'label' => 'Building Number',
        'backend_type' => 'varchar',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'is_user_defined' => 1,
        'is_system' => 0,
        'is_visible' => 1,        
        'is_required' => 1,
        'multiline_count' => 0,
        'validate_rules' => array(
            'max_text_length' => 255,
           'min_text_length' => 1
        ),
    ),
);
```

Please let me know how to add a label for my field.

Comment: Open eav_attribute table and search for buildingnumber attribute_code and check field frontend_label

Comment: Thanks worked. Please write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open eav_attribute table and search for buildingnumber attribute_code and check field frontend_label